# jquery toggle based on contains image

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display block when the image with the class `.default` is in the DOM but I need to hide the `.full` and `.del` when the page loads.  Any suggestions on how to get this to work as my toggle is not functioning properly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.itemcontrols .full').css("display", "none");
    $('.itemcontrols .del').css("display", "none");

    var toggle = $('.item .default');

    if (toggle.length > 1) {
        $(toggle).parent().find('.itemcontrols .full').css("display", "block");
        $(toggle).parent().find('.itemcontrols .del').css("display", "block");   
    } else {

    }
});


<div class="item item1 ui-state-default">
    <img src="9228321128.png" alt="" class="default">     
    <div class="itemcontrols">
        <div id="add1">
            <img src="img/photo_24.png" class="icon">
        </div>
        <div class="full">
            <img src="img/resize_24.png" class="icon">
        </div>
        <div class="del">
            <img src="img/trash_24.png" class="icon">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also must add .default isn't in every .item div so that's why I'm trying to toggle based on if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if (toggle.length >= 1)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/aEkqY/

Comment: Thanks that worked I guess I just confused the greater than or equal to.